# Compare two derived type variables using gfortran (gcc8)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have the following derived type:

```
type datetime
    integer     :: year
    integer     :: month
    integer     :: day
    integer     :: hour
    integer     :: minute
end type
```

I have two variables defined with this type:

```
type(datetime)                          :: session_end
type(datetime)                          :: session_cursor
```

And I am trying to compare both variables, to see if derived type elements have same values or not.

```
do while (session_cursor /= session_end)
    ...
end do
```

But I get:

```
do while (session_cursor /= session_end)
         1
Error: Operands of comparison operator '/=' at (1) are TYPE(datetime)/TYPE(datetime)
```

I am using gfortran (gcc8) under FreeBSD 12 64 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with gfortran and as is I get the same error message. The code will work if individual variables of the datetime are compared. 
Probably you have to use overloading because comparison is not defined for your type. Check this example on how to overload that I found https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys466/sp2013/comp_info/overload.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info about overloading, I will give it a try. As a workaround I wrote the function to return .true. or .false. checking on individual variables of both datetime derived types -as you suggest in the answer-.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to operations, such as the comparison operation desired here, there are two distinct types: *intrinsic* operations and *defined* operations.

Intrinsic operations are those that the compiler 'knows about by default' and defined operations are those provided by the code being compiled/used.

An intrinsic comparison operation is provided only for intrinsic types. For intrinsic unary operators (such as unary minus `-`) the operand must be of intrinsic type; for intrinsic binary operators both operands must be of intrinsic types.

Even for equality and inequality, a defined operation must be used for derived types.  The error message of the question is saying that no such defined operation is known/accessible by the compiler.  Other compilers may give messages such as

> error #6355: This binary operation is invalid for this data type.

or

> Operands to .NE. operator are of derived type

or

> 1511-026 (S) Type of operand is not permitted for comparison operation.

Because there is no defined operation available the compiler is left to consider the derived types as operands for the intrinsic operation - which is not allowed.

To provide a defined operation we first provide a function.  It makes sense for this function to return a true/false value, taking two operands of this derived type, not modifying them:

```
logical function datetime_unequal(lhs, rhs)
   class(datetime), intent(in) :: lhs, rhs
   datetime_unequal = ...   ! Implement inequality test
end function datetime_unequal
```

We can use this function in the obvious way (not as an operator):

```
do while (datetime_unequal(session_cursor, session_end)))
...
end do
```

This may suffice for many purposes, but we can continue with our approach of making a defined comparison operation.  (For consistency, we're going to call our operator `/=`.)  We do this by providing a generic interface or generic binding overloading `operator(/=)`.

Consider

```
module datetime_mod
  implicit none

  type datetime
    ...
  contains
    procedure datetime_unequal
    ! A generic binding
    generic :: operator(/=) => datetime_unequal
  end type

! A generic interface
  interface operator(/=)
    module procedure datetime_unequal 
  end interface

contains

  logical function datetime_unequal(lhs, rhs)
    class(datetime), intent(in) :: lhs, rhs
    datetime_unequal = ...   ! Implement inequality test
  end function datetime_unequal

end module datetime_mod
```

Note that you don't need to provide both the generic interface and the generic binding.  Indeed, in most cases the generic binding (defined inside the type definition) is preferable: it is accessible whenever the type definition itself is accessible; the generic interface has independent accessibility.

Note also that the arguments to the comparison function are polymorphic (`class(datetime)`) to allow it to be used as a type-bound procedure.  With the standalone function this would not be necessary.

Finally, much of this discussion holds for more general (binary) operations, not just those that overload the intrinsic ones.